# ios:createIPA gradle task fails with error in HfsCompressor.compressNative

Tags: ios, libgdx, robovm

When building my libGDX game for iOS from the command line, using `./gradlew ios:createIPA`, I sometimes get the following error:

```
...
:ios_lite:createIPA
RoboVM has detected that you are running on a slow HDD. Please consider mounting a RAM disk.
To create a 2GB RAM disk, run this in your terminal:
SIZE=2048 ; diskutil erasevolume HFS+ 'RoboVM RAM Disk' `hdiutil attach -nomount ram://$((SIZE * 2048))`
See http://docs.robovm.com/ for more info
RoboVM has detected that you are running on a slow HDD. Please consider mounting a RAM disk.
To create a 2GB RAM disk, run this in your terminal:
SIZE=2048 ; diskutil erasevolume HFS+ 'RoboVM RAM Disk' `hdiutil attach -nomount ram://$((SIZE * 2048))`
See http://docs.robovm.com/ for more info
:ios_lite:createIPA FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':ios_lite:createIPA'.
> org.robovm.compiler.util.io.HfsCompressor.compressNative(Ljava/lang/String;[BI)Z

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

`--info` and `--debug` provide much more output, but no more useful information, and `--stacktrace` just shows the internal stack trace within Gradle.

Using Gradle 2.2, OS X 10.11.5, JVM 1.8.0_74, RoboVM 1.12.0.

What causes this error, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know what's causing it (better answers welcome in that regard), but I have found a workaround: restart the Gradle daemon. Before building, simply run:

```
$ ./gradlew --stop
```

The daemon will automatically be restarted for the next build. So far, this workaround has reliably fixed the error for me.